How to write text from a multiline textbox into a text file, while maintaining formatting?
I am attempting to write the text from a multiline textbox to a .txt file. When using either
.Write
or
.Writeline
I achieve the same result of all of the data being contained to a single line. I have attempted to split the text every 100 characters which partially works. I have also attempted to make an array and set the value as the textbox text, with no success. The textbox will contain 1 to 3 paragraphs inside of it.
What is the best way to approach this to format it to multiple lines so it is legible?

Are there actual new lines or is it just wrapping the text?

@CoolCoder123 The multiline textbox is wrapping if I'm understanding your question correctly. This program is for writing reports. So they're in paragraph form. When output to the text file it's one long line.

Right. Now, you haven't posted any code that shows your best attempt at this, and you should. The Lines property of a TextBoxBase (TextBox and RichTextBox) Control gives you the logical lines of text (the text sections separated by \r\n). You need the physical lines instead (lines generated when wrapping the text inside a container). The number of physical lines can be retrieved using GetLineFromCharIndex(), passing the [TextBox].TextLenght. Now, you can iterate that value, and use the GetFirstCharIndexFromLine() method to get the index of the first character of each physical line

There is no "formatting". If your TextBox is wrapping the text then that's simply how it is displayed. If you were to change the width of the TextBox, the text would reflow the number of lines and characters per line would change. If you want actual line breaks in your text then you should be adding actual line breaks into the TextBox, not relying on word wrap. If you actually enter a line break then it becomes part of the text and saving the text to a file will save the line break too.

@jimi ok thank you, I will do this. Do you recommend a richtextbox or multiline for this purpose?

There's no point using a RichTextBox unless you want RTF formatting. Both the RichTextBox and TextBox controls inherit TextBoxBase and that's where the functionality mentioned by Jimi comes from.

Maybe you just need to to enable wrapping in whatever program is used to view the .txt file. For example, in Notepad in Windows: "Format" menu -> enable "Word Wrap".

Try this, based off the little-known GetFirstCharIndexFromLine() method:
public IEnumerable<string> GetWrappedLines(tb As TextBox)
{
    if (!tb.Multiline) 
    {
        yield return tb.Text;
        return break;
    }

    bool continueProcess = true;
    int i = 1; //Zero Based So Start from 1
    int j = 0;
    while (continueProcess)
    {
        var index = tb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            yield return textBox1.Text.Substring(j, index - j);
            j = index;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return tb.Text.Substring(j, tb.Text.Length - j));
            continueProcess = false;
        }
    }
}

But honestly I wouldn't bother. The line breaks you see on screen are based on wrapping logic and not actually present in the underlying text. If you close your program and the later use it to re-open the same text file, with the missing line breaks, you'll see it wraps again.
